# If else in stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure as follow:

```
Create Procedure sp_ADD_USER_EXTRANET_CLIENT_INDEX_PHY
(
@ParLngId int output
)
as
Begin
    SET @ParLngId = (Select top 1 ParLngId from T_Param where ParStrNom = 'Extranet Client')
    if(@ParLngId = 0)
        begin
            Insert Into T_Param values ('PHY', 'Extranet Client', Null, Null, 'T', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL)
            SET @ParLngId = @@IDENTITY
        End
    Return @ParLngId
End
```

So I set a variable `@ParLngId`, I check if there is a such data in a table, if yes, I return the value, if not I insert one and return the variable which contains the Id of the inserted line... But now it shows me an SqlException:

> Subquery returned more values. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when used as an expression.

Somebody has a solution ?

Comment: "an error saying that different values have been returned" - could you edit in the exact text of the error message for us please?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact error message?

Comment: I've just edited the post

Comment: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Comment: Yes but When you add a procedure in sql server, it verifies first if there is not a procedure with the same name before adding it

Comment: When you got the error, did you really have `top 1` in your `SET @ParLngId = (select…`? I’d expect that error to be raised only if that subquery returned multiple rows. Do you know what line the error was coming from?

Comment: This video helped me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpLQYVErKm8&ab_channel=kudvenkat

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers but I figured out how to do it and the final procedure looks like that :

```
Create Procedure sp_ADD_RESPONSABLE_EXTRANET_CLIENT
(
@ParLngId int output
)
as
Begin
if not exists (Select ParLngId from T_Param where ParStrIndex = 'RES' and ParStrP2 = 'Web')
    Begin
            INSERT INTO T_Param values('RES','¤ExtranetClient', 'ECli', 'Web', 1, 1, Null, Null, 'non', 'ExtranetClient', 'ExtranetClient', 25032, Null, 'informatique.interne@company.fr', 'Extranet-Client', Null, 27, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, 1, Null, Null, 0 )
            SET @ParLngId = @@IDENTITY
    End
Else
    Begin
            SET @ParLngId = (Select top 1 ParLngId from T_Param where ParStrNom = 'Extranet Client')
            Return @ParLngId
    End   
End
```

So the thing that I found out and which made it works is:

> if not exists

It allows us to use a boolean instead of **Null** or **0** or a number resulted of **count()**

Answer (score 11):

If there are no matching row/s then `@ParLngId` will be `NULL` not zero, so you need `IF @ParLngId IS NULL`.

You should also use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` rather than `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: @@Identity works. It works before when I didn't need to use the Else If, I don't think that problem comes from it

Answer (score 9):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ADD_USER_EXTRANET_CLIENT_INDEX_PHY
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ParLngId INT
    SELECT TOP 1 @ParLngId = ParLngId
    FROM dbo.T_Param
    WHERE ParStrNom = 'Extranet Client'

    IF (@ParLngId = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.T_Param
        VALUES ('PHY', 'Extranet Client', NULL, NULL, 'T', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL)

        RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
    ELSE BEGIN

        RETURN @ParLngId 

    END

END
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this with join query statements

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteItem]
@ItemId int = 0 
AS
 Begin
 DECLARE @cnt int;

SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT @cnt =COUNT(ttm.Id) 
    from ItemTransaction itr INNER JOIN ItemUnitMeasurement ium 
        ON itr.Id = ium.ItemTransactionId  INNER JOIN ItemMaster im 
        ON itr.ItemId = im.Id INNER JOIN TransactionTypeMaster ttm 
        ON itr.TransactionTypeMasterId = ttm.Id 
        where im.Id = @ItemId

if(@cnt = 1)
    Begin
    DECLARE @transactionType varchar(255);
    DECLARE @mesurementAmount float;
    DECLARE @itemTransactionId int;
    DECLARE @itemUnitMeasurementId int;

        SELECT @transactionType = ttm.TransactionType,  @mesurementAmount = ium.Amount, @itemTransactionId = itr.Id, @itemUnitMeasurementId = ium.Id
        from ItemTransaction itr INNER JOIN ItemUnitMeasurement ium 
            ON itr.Id = ium.ItemTransactionId INNER JOIN TransactionTypeMaster ttm 
            ON itr.TransactionTypeMasterId = ttm.Id 
            where itr.ItemId = @ItemId  
        if(@transactionType = 'Close' and @mesurementAmount = 0)
            Begin
                delete from ItemUnitMeasurement where Id = @itemUnitMeasurementId;

            End
        else
            Begin
                delete from ItemTransaction where Id = @itemTransactionId;
            End
    End
else
 Begin
    delete from ItemMaster where Id = @ItemId;
 End
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if not exists (select dist_id from tbl_stock where dist_id= @cust_id and item_id=@item_id)
    insert into tbl_stock(dist_id,item_id,qty)values(@cust_id, @item_id, @qty); 
else
    update tbl_stock set qty=(qty + @qty) where dist_id= @cust_id and item_id= @item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to have the RETURN stament.

Have anther look at [Using a Stored Procedure with Output Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx)

Also have another look at the OUT section in [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Procedure Sql:

```
Create Procedure sp_ADD_USER_EXTRANET_CLIENT_INDEX_PHY
(
@ParLngId int output
)
as
Begin
    -- Min will return only 1 value, if 'Extranet Client' is found
    -- IsNull will take care of 'Extranet Client' not found, returning 0 instead of Null
    -- But T_Param must be a Master Table with ParStrNom having a Unique Index, if so Min is not reqd at all
    -- But 'PHY', 'Extranet Client' suggests that Unique Key has 2 columns, not just ParStrNom

    SET @ParLngId = IsNull((Select Min (ParLngId) from T_Param where ParStrNom = 'Extranet Client'), 0);

    -- Nothing changed below

    if  (@ParLngId = 0)
        Begin
            Insert Into T_Param values ('PHY', 'Extranet Client', Null, Null, 'T', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL)
            SET @ParLngId = @@IDENTITY
    End

    Return  @ParLngId
    End
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of writing:

```
Select top 1 ParLngId from T_Param where ParStrNom = 'Extranet Client'
```

Write:

```
Select top 1 ParLngId from T_Param where ParStrNom IN 'Extranet Client'
```

i.e. replace `'='` sign by `'IN'`